# FSharp.Data.SqlClient Type Provider on machine without SQL installed (CI server)

Tags: f#, continuous-integration, type-providers, build-server, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I've started using [FSharp.Data.SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/index.html) type provider lately and I'm having trouble to make it work with [AppVeyor](http://www.appveyor.com/) build system.

Problem is, that on the machine build is running at, there is no database running, so specifying local connection string makes build fails, because Type Provider is not able to get table structure data out of database.

**Is there a way to specify some kind of local file which would contain database structure information (e.g. as dbml?)?**

I could probably create a publicly available database, add read-only credentials and point type provider to that database, so it could be accessed from build server, but I don't like that idea.

Comment: `SqlDataConnection` and `SqlEntityConnection` from the standard library have parameters `LocalSchemaFile` and `ForceUpdate` for this purpose, but it seems `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` doesn't have an equivalent. I suggest you to add a request for it on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/issues), because it's indeed often necessary.

Comment: As far as I know, AppVeyor supports Sql Express as a part of build process. You can have mdf file attached to it as pre-build step.